# Redundant snapshot listeners and reads

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

So I'm curious as to how many reads redundant snapshot listeners do, both from a performance standpoint but also a pricing standpoint. I need to decide whether to wrap this in an `PublishSubject` from Rxdart to form an intermediate "caching" layer.

Let's say I have a collection with 10 documents called `mycol`, and the following code:

```js
final sub1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('mycol').snapshots().listen((qs) {
   // ... do something with the snapshot data.
});

// A few minutes later (sub1 is still active):
final sub2 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('mycol').snapshots().listen((qs) {
   // ... do something with the snapshot data.
});
```

Will the above count as 20 reads?

Because the following from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens) comes to mind:

> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for
> example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as
> if you had issued a brand-new query.

This hints at **redundant queries to the same collection not being charged for the redundant reads**, as it would be pretty easy for the SDK to share that data between active listeners. But I've never really understood that quote.

So my questions are:

- How many reads does the example above do?
- Is my understanding of the quote correct?

*I could just use the `PublishSubject` in a "better safe than sorry" kind of way, but I dislike writing redundant layers due to a lack of understanding.*

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question and if it does indeed mean redundant queries to the same collection not being charged for the redundant reads does it require persistent caching to be enabled in the SDK?

Comment: Never got an answer, no

Answer (score 0):

I suggest solving your issue by using some of the available metrics from Firestore. You can inspect metrics available in Firestore using Cloud Monitoring [1].

Among them, using the metric *document/read_count* you should be able to answer your question if you can isolate your database from other users, in order to be able to identify how many reads are done by your code and avoid counting other reads.

There is more information about monitoring Cloud Firestore activity in [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-firestore

[2] https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage